# Match-Merge in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, sas, dplyr

I'm working on migrating some SAS programs into R, and I'm having a difficult time figuring out the best way to accomplish this seemingly simple bit of logic.

```
proc sort data=df1; by cridsessid mode refresh_key; run;
proc sort data=df2; by cridsessid mode refresh_key; run;

data df3;
  merge df1(in=xx) df2(in=yy);
  by cridsessid mode refresh_key;
  if xx and yy then do;
    cridsessid=catx(':',cridsessid,refresh_key2);
  end;
run;;
```

The data sets are difficult because there may only be a few thousand rows that actually match `xx` and `yy` out of millions of rows, but the basic output looks like this:

**df1**

```
                           transId_app mode                 sm_bdt                 sm_edt
1 c3bca1af-ed0d-4403-9552-29758055f7a3 None 21MAR2016:07:07:56.611 21MAR2016:07:07:56.627
2 68f85148-6b75-49dc-90f9-5bb66b6a750b None 21MAR2016:07:07:56.940 21MAR2016:07:07:56.940
3 68f85148-6b75-49dc-90f9-5bb66b6a750b None 21MAR2016:07:07:56.940 21MAR2016:07:07:56.955
4 68f85148-6b75-49dc-90f9-5bb66b6a750b None 21MAR2016:07:07:56.940 21MAR2016:07:07:56.940
5 68f85148-6b75-49dc-90f9-5bb66b6a750b None 21MAR2016:07:07:56.924 21MAR2016:07:07:56.940
6 7a0c53a3-00b4-4b81-8238-24a738e5f4ed None 21MAR2016:07:08:33.003 21MAR2016:07:08:33.003
  mode_                                                                cridsessid
1 Pass1 0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2
2 Pass1 0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2
3 Pass1 0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2
4 Pass1 0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2
5 Pass1 0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2
6 Pass1 0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2
  refresh_key
1       7.125
2       7.125
3       7.125
4       7.125
5       7.125
6       7.142
```

with a `dput()` of

```
structure(list(transId_app = c("c3bca1af-ed0d-4403-9552-29758055f7a3", 
"68f85148-6b75-49dc-90f9-5bb66b6a750b", "68f85148-6b75-49dc-90f9-5bb66b6a750b", 
"68f85148-6b75-49dc-90f9-5bb66b6a750b", "68f85148-6b75-49dc-90f9-5bb66b6a750b", 
"7a0c53a3-00b4-4b81-8238-24a738e5f4ed", "7a0c53a3-00b4-4b81-8238-24a738e5f4ed", 
"7a0c53a3-00b4-4b81-8238-24a738e5f4ed", "7a0c53a3-00b4-4b81-8238-24a738e5f4ed"
), mode = c("None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", 
"None", "None"), sm_bdt = c("21MAR2016:07:07:56.611", "21MAR2016:07:07:56.940", 
"21MAR2016:07:07:56.940", "21MAR2016:07:07:56.940", "21MAR2016:07:07:56.924", 
"21MAR2016:07:08:33.003", "21MAR2016:07:08:33.003", "21MAR2016:07:08:32.988", 
"21MAR2016:07:08:32.957"), sm_edt = c("21MAR2016:07:07:56.627", 
"21MAR2016:07:07:56.940", "21MAR2016:07:07:56.955", "21MAR2016:07:07:56.940", 
"21MAR2016:07:07:56.940", "21MAR2016:07:08:33.003", "21MAR2016:07:08:33.003", 
"21MAR2016:07:08:33.003", "21MAR2016:07:08:33.003"), mode_ = c("Pass1", 
"Pass1", "Pass1", "Pass1", "Pass1", "Pass1", "Pass1", "Pass1", 
"Pass1"), cridsessid = c("0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2", 
"0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2", 
"0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2", 
"0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2", 
"0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2", 
"0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2", 
"0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2", 
"0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2", 
"0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2"
), refresh_key = c(7.125, 7.125, 7.125, 7.125, 7.125, 7.142, 
7.142, 7.142, 7.142)), .Names = c("transId_app", "mode", "sm_bdt", 
"sm_edt", "mode_", "cridsessid", "refresh_key"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
9L))
```

**df2**

```
              mode
1             None
2             None
3 LazyLoadUncached
4             None
5 LazyLoadUncached
6             None
                                                                 cridsessid refresh_key_
1 0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2      7.142+0
2 0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2      7.142+0
3 00e8a4c5-904d-46a4-a7b1-e4e6383bdd10:bf97d617-fbe8-4c4d-ab0e-c00d48bce120      0.317+0
4 00e8a4c5-904d-46a4-a7b1-e4e6383bdd10:bf97d617-fbe8-4c4d-ab0e-c00d48bce120      0.317+0
5 02063ca4-ccf3-4326-b87d-fe5ab13d2d7f:07783670-5ace-47bc-a707-db5b8064e241     5.658+17
6 02063ca4-ccf3-4326-b87d-fe5ab13d2d7f:07783670-5ace-47bc-a707-db5b8064e241     5.658+17
  refresh_key refresh_key2
1       7.142        7.142
2       7.142        7.142
3       0.317        0.317
4       0.317        0.317
5       5.658        5.658
6       5.658        5.658
```

with a `dput()` of

```
structure(list(mode = c("None", "None", "LazyLoadUncached", "None", 
"LazyLoadUncached", "None"), cridsessid = c("0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2", 
"0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2", 
"00e8a4c5-904d-46a4-a7b1-e4e6383bdd10:bf97d617-fbe8-4c4d-ab0e-c00d48bce120", 
"00e8a4c5-904d-46a4-a7b1-e4e6383bdd10:bf97d617-fbe8-4c4d-ab0e-c00d48bce120", 
"02063ca4-ccf3-4326-b87d-fe5ab13d2d7f:07783670-5ace-47bc-a707-db5b8064e241", 
"02063ca4-ccf3-4326-b87d-fe5ab13d2d7f:07783670-5ace-47bc-a707-db5b8064e241"
), refresh_key_ = c("7.142+0", "7.142+0", "0.317+0", "0.317+0", 
"5.658+17", "5.658+17"), refresh_key = c(7.142, 7.142, 0.317, 
0.317, 5.658, 5.658), refresh_key2 = c(7.142, 7.142, 0.317, 0.317, 
5.658, 5.658)), .Names = c("mode", "cridsessid", "refresh_key_", 
"refresh_key", "refresh_key2"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

**df3**

```
                           transId_app mode                 sm_bdt                 sm_edt
1 7a0c53a3-00b4-4b81-8238-24a738e5f4ed None 21MAR2016:07:08:33.003 21MAR2016:07:08:33.003
2 7a0c53a3-00b4-4b81-8238-24a738e5f4ed None 21MAR2016:07:08:33.003 21MAR2016:07:08:33.003
3 7a0c53a3-00b4-4b81-8238-24a738e5f4ed None 21MAR2016:07:08:32.988 21MAR2016:07:08:33.003
4 7a0c53a3-00b4-4b81-8238-24a738e5f4ed None 21MAR2016:07:08:32.957 21MAR2016:07:08:33.003
  mode_                                                                      cridsessid
1 Pass1 0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2:7.142
2 Pass1 0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2:7.142
3 Pass1 0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2:7.142
4 Pass1 0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2:7.142
  refresh_key refresh_key_ refresh_key2
1       7.142      7.142+0        7.142
2       7.142      7.142+0        7.142
3       7.142      7.142+0        7.142
4       7.142      7.142+0        7.142
```

with a `dput()` of

```
structure(list(transId_app = c("7a0c53a3-00b4-4b81-8238-24a738e5f4ed", 
"7a0c53a3-00b4-4b81-8238-24a738e5f4ed", "7a0c53a3-00b4-4b81-8238-24a738e5f4ed", 
"7a0c53a3-00b4-4b81-8238-24a738e5f4ed"), mode = c("None", "None", 
"None", "None"), sm_bdt = c("21MAR2016:07:08:33.003", "21MAR2016:07:08:33.003", 
"21MAR2016:07:08:32.988", "21MAR2016:07:08:32.957"), sm_edt = c("21MAR2016:07:08:33.003", 
"21MAR2016:07:08:33.003", "21MAR2016:07:08:33.003", "21MAR2016:07:08:33.003"
), mode_ = c("Pass1", "Pass1", "Pass1", "Pass1"), cridsessid = c("0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2:7.142", 
"0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2:7.142", 
"0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2:7.142", 
"0043dfb7-9a98-4b7c-9c04-5afc05580843:96530555-3568-468c-9bb4-ddd77278f1b2:7.142"
), refresh_key = c(7.142, 7.142, 7.142, 7.142), refresh_key_ = c("7.142+0", 
"7.142+0", "7.142+0", "7.142+0"), refresh_key2 = c(7.142, 7.142, 
7.142, 7.142)), .Names = c("transId_app", "mode", "sm_bdt", "sm_edt", 
"mode_", "cridsessid", "refresh_key", "refresh_key_", "refresh_key2"
), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am aware of `semi_join()` in dplyr, and think it could effectively replace the `if xx and yy`, but `semi_join()` returns a data.frame, I'm not sure how I would get a Logical Vector that I could use to do something like this:

```
df <- full_join(df1, df2, by="cridsessid", "mode", "refresh_key")
x <- {logical vector}
df[x, "cridsessid"] <- df[x, paste("cridsessid", "mode", sep=":")]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and expected output

Comment: That example has no matches for `cressid` and should also have been produced with `dput` to allow pasting into a running R session.

Comment: added dput() out put. Thank you. Like I said,..still learning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear in the absence of a small couple of input sets and an output dataset what SAS would return. (What sort of join does a SAS merge return?) I would have imagined that xx and yy would all have been TRUE for an inner join. You would then have just done an assignment to `var1` of the values of the pasted `var1`,":",`var2`. I'm not using `inner_join` since that is the default action of the base function `merge`:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by="var1", "var2", "var3")

df3["var1"] <- with(df3, paste0(var1, var4, sep=":"))
```

Comment: good catch, I missed that, and updated to `full_join()` as that's what it should be. I also added some small example data. Thank you.

Comment: If you want a full-join then use `all=TRUE` as a parameter to `merge` and then test for NA values, but your example has no matches for at least one of its matching criteria. So it cannot really be used for useful demonstration.

Comment: The testing for NA values was the key that I was looking for. So simple, I can't believe I didn't see that earlier. Thank you so much for your help.